# How to set value on $rootScope after angular.bootstrap()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular.bootstrap() to initialize my app. I want to assign some values to my $rootScope after this. I am trying this but it is not working for me:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
var modulesToLoad = ['myApp'];
angular.bootstrap(b, modulesToLoad);
app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.isLoading = false;
}
```

Comment: You can inject `$rootScope` into any service / controller and manipulate it from there. Could you elaborate a bit more about your use case?

Answer (score 7):

The bootstrap function returns the `$injector`, so you could do something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
var modulesToLoad = ['myApp'];
var injector = angular.bootstrap(b, modulesToLoad);
injector.invoke(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.isLoading = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
    {{globalText}}
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      {{localText}}
    </div> 

var myModule = angular.module('app2', []);
myModule.value('globalText', 'GLOBAL');
myModule.run(function($rootScope, globalText) {

  $rootScope.globalText = globalText;
});

myModule.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.localText = 'LOCAL';
});
```